# Either .each do or .all isn't working how I think it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So whenever someone rates  a shop, I want the Shop model to calculate its new average rating and store that in the database (instead of calculating the average every time someone looks at it).  So I wrote the segment of code that follows, and it doesn't work.

The loop always iterates exactly once, no matter how many shop_ratings in the database exist that have the shop's id as their shop_id.  I played around with it a bit and found that every time a new rating is submitted the function is called successfully, but it only runs the loop once and sets the average to what the first rating was.

I don't know if the "query" that sets the ratings variable is wrong or if it's the loop that's wrong.

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shop_ratings

  attr_accessible :name, :latitude, :longitude

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :latitude
  validates_presence_of :longitude

  def distance_to(lat, long)
    return (self.longitude - long) + (self.latitude - lat)
  end

  def find_average

    total = 0
    count = 0
    ratings = ShopRating.all(:conditions => {:shop_id => id})
    ratings.each do |submission|
      total = total +  submission.rating
      count = count + 1
    end
    update_attribute :average_rating, total/count
  end      

end
```

Comment: why use ShopRating.all(...) ? -> self.show_ratings, since a Shop `has_many :shop_ratings`. And distances calculated adding longs and lats?

Comment: Replace `total=0` with `total=0.0`, for the reason described in @kvirani's answer. Replace `ratings = ShopRating.all(...); ratings.each ...` with `shop_ratings.each ...` for the reason decribed in @tokland's comment. Also, `find_average` shouldn't be updating `average_rating` attribute, it should just return the avg. Another method could take that and perform the update. The task of finding averages shouldn't be coupled to the task of updating your attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better find_average method (btw, it should be called set_average_rating because you are not finding it, you are saving it)

#### shop.rb - Replacement for: find_average

```
def set_average_rating
  update_attribute(:average_rating, shop_ratings.average(:rating))
end
```

As you can see, we are leveraging AR's average calculation method, which returns a float. Doc: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M000293

Speaking of floats, the reason your existing code *seems* to not be calculating the average correctly is likely b/c you are not telling ruby that the final average is to be a float, not an integer. Hopefully you have defined your shop#average_rating field to be a float or decimal and not an integer.

Comment: To elaborate on what I wrote in the last paragraph there, if you have 2 ratings, 1 and 2 stars accordingly, then you would expect an average of 1.5.

However, 

1 + 2 = 3. 
And 3 / 2 = 1 (as an integer calculation).

Which would make you think that it is not looking at the second rating, but it did.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I did a bad job of testing for that type of event.  Also thanks for letting me know a .average command exists.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know what happens, put some debug information into your code:

```
    ratings = ShopRating.all(:conditions => {:shop_id => id})
    # add this log
    Rails.logger.info "==== the raings of this Shop: #{ratings.inspect}"
    ratings.each do |submission|
```

and probably you will see the ratings only contains 1 element.

so, I suggest you re-implement your code :

change:

```
# previous: 
ratings = ShopRating.all(:conditions => {:shop_id => id})  
ratings.each do |submission|
```

to be:

```
# because you already defined  :
# has_many :shop_ratings
shop_ratings.each do |submission|
```